# Handsontable 7.4 dropdown cell with falsy value (0) shows placeholder

Tags: handsontable, falsy

I am looking for a way to display the numeric value 0 in a dropdown list that also includes placeholder text when the cell is empty. Currently, if 0 is selected the placeholder text shows through. I'm hoping for a built-in option and I'd like to avoid casting the number to string and back if I can (that would tear up my current validation scheme). The following example is modified from the HandsOnTable dropdown docs. The 'Chassis Color' column contains the issue.

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/y3pL0vjq/

snippet:

```
  function getCarData() {
    return [
      ["Tesla", 2017, "black", "black"],
      ["Nissan", 2018, "blue", "blue"],
      ["Chrysler", 2019, "yellow", "black"],
      ["Volvo", 2020, "white", "gray"]
    ];
  }
  var
    container = document.getElementById('example1'),
    hot;
  hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: getCarData(),
    colHeaders: ['Car', 'Year', 'Chassis color', 'Bumper color'],
    columns: [
      {},
      {type: 'numeric'},
      {
        type: 'dropdown',
        placeholder: "blah",
        source: [null, 0, 1, 2, 3]
      },
      {
        type: 'dropdown',
        source: ['yellow', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue', 'gray', 'black', 'white']
      }
    ]
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found to handle this dropdown list of numbers is to omit the "type" attribute and specify the editor and validator as 'autocomplete. Then make a custom renderer to merge the NumericRenderer functionality with the autocomplete dropdown list.

To finalize the similar look and feel of the native dropdown function, you then add "strict: true" and "filter: false", as explained in the dropdown docs.

> Internally, cell {type: "dropdown"} is equivalent to cell {type: "autocomplete", strict: true, filter: false}.
> [Dropdown Docs](https://handsontable.com/docs/7.4.2/demo-dropdown.html)

Example:

```
  function getCarData() {
    return [
      ["Tesla", 2017, null, "black"],
      ["Nissan", 2018, 0, "blue"],
      ["Chrysler", 2019, 1, "black"],
      ["Volvo", 2020, 2, "gray"]
    ];
  }
  var
    container = document.getElementById('example1'),
    hot;

  function myRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.renderers.NumericRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
    td.innerHTML += '<div class="htAutocompleteArrow">▼</div>'
  }
  
  hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: getCarData(),
    colHeaders: ['Car', 'Year', 'Chassis color', 'Bumper color'],
    columns: [
      {},
      {type: 'numeric'},
      {
        editor: 'autocomplete',
        validator: 'autocomplete',
        renderer: myRenderer,
        strict: true,
        filter: false,
        placeholder: "blah",
        source: [null, 0, 1, 2, 3]
      },
      {
        type: 'dropdown',
        source: ['yellow', 'red', 'orange', 'green', 'blue', 'gray', 'black', 'white']
      }
    ]
  });
```